# values of sessions vaiables are getting unset i.e. "-blank-" without unsseting it

Tags: php, session, session-variables, unset

```
include('conection.php');
$db=new Database();
session_start();
echo "<div style=' background-color:white; border:solid white'>".$_SESSION['uid']."</div>";
if(!(isset(**$_SESSION['uid']**)))
{
    header('location:index.php');
}
if(isset($_REQUEST['admin']))
{
    if(base64_decode($_REQUEST['admin'])!=='over779656')
    {
        header('location:index.php');
    }
}
$r=explode(" ",base64_decode($_REQUEST['final']));



   **$_SESSION['uid']**
```

value of this variable is getting unset after time cross 2 hours or some more than that, why is it so, even i am not unssetting any variable, is there any server problem or any browser problem

Comment: is it because of session expires? session timeout?

Comment: Make changes in your ini file and restart your server, also use `exit` after header

Comment: If your php.ini is on live server with many projects using the same ini file or you dont have access to it. Try my answer.

Answer (score 3):

check `session.gc_maxlifetime`  in yout `php.ini` and increase the time there

Comment: it is 1440, means how mush time in minutes

Comment: acutally that code is uploaded on server , where shpuld in check php.ini on server

Comment: use phpinfo() in a php file and find out where php.ini is

Comment: doing `php -i | grep php.ini` on the server will show you hopefully

Answer (score 2):

Instead of changing this in php.ini, try this to change the timeout during runtime.

`ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 5*60*60); // 5 hours`

**EDIT**

NOTE: Use this code before `session_start()`

Comment: no this is not working at alll... any other alternative option

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have access to php.ini and/or do not want to restart your server you may try the following. Look at the session.gc_maxlifetime setting with http://php.net/ini_get like so:

```
    ini_get('session.gc_maxlifetime')
```

and you may set it with http://php.net/ini_set like so

```
    ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 3600*24);
```

Beware of memory issues and long running scripts though. Also like another answer says: execute before session_start().